# Jquery iterate through html elements in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I currently have refactored some code and am getting hung up on some jquery usage. Before, I was using a jquery `each()` loop and iterating through dom elements like this:

```
$.each($('[id*="cnv"]'), function (index, value) { /*do work*/ }
```

and this will select each element who's ID contains `cnv`. Now I have moved the code and need to iterate through these elements but from outside the iframe that they live in. I access these elements in various places using javascript as follows

```
var canvasObj = window.frames['iframe'].contentDocument.getElementById(canvasId);
```

(note: `iframe` is the id/name of my iframe) but I am  not sure how to combine these two statements so that I can iterate through elements with matching ids from a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```
$("#iFrameId").contents().find('[id*="cnv"]').each(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can use `contents()` to access inside iframe

```
//assuming iframe has loaded
$('#iframe').contents().find('[id*="cnv"]').doSomething()
```